# HTML5 Geolocation iPhone UIWebView

Tags: jquery, ios, html, uiwebview, gps

I have an HTML5 page with query that I am embedding in a UIWebView in the iPhone.
This site uses the users current location with Javascript. And this works nicely.
However the alert dialog to use the users location popes up every time the user starts
the App. The thing is that the usual popup for allowing GPS-access only popes up once,
but after this another popup from the UIWebview popes up, and this one pops up every time you launch the app.

Is there anyway to store the users choice and allow GPS automatically after the first launch.

//ObjectiveCoder

Answer (score 1):

if you want to embed HTML5 pages inside your app i suggest you use [PhoneGap](https://phonegap.com/).
 it also has a [built in syntax for getting locations](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html#Geolocation) natively so the popup that the browser generates will prevent.

Comment: This is what I was going to answer. I would also add that UIWebView will run its policy check every time its instantiated. To get around this problem Phonegap overrides the UIWebView navigator.geolocation methods with their owns calls.